# ASP.NET - with multiple sites sharing the same database, how can I manage the username a password?

Tags: asp.net, database, web-config, app-config, user-management

I have multiple websites and a Windows app that share the same database. Is there a way that I can manage the database username and password across all web.configs and app.configs? I'd like to be able to change the username and password, and then have all websites and apps use the new name. Is there something that I can use that will automate this? I currently store the username and password in a connection string.

Comment: Potentially yes, but unless you are needing to frequently update all these connection strings (and that sounds of some kind of bad design), manually updating a couple of apps is going to be a lot quicker and easier than writing something to go ahead and make new config files.

Comment: Well we have one core website, and then we can have any number of sites installed that use the same database. I wouldn't want our IT dept to manually configure every web.config for each site installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to write some custom code in your Windows app to support it, but ASP.NET Membership will let you share usernames and passwords among multiple apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

> ASP.NET membership supports facilities for:
>
> Creating new users and passwords.
>
> Storing membership information (user names, passwords, and supporting
>   data) in Microsoft SQL Server, Active Directory, or an alternative
>   data store.
>
> Authenticating users who visit your site. You can authenticate users
>   programmatically, or you can use the ASP.NET login controls to create
>   a complete authentication system that requires little or no code.
>
> Managing passwords, which includes creating, changing, and resetting
>   them . Depending on membership options you choose, the membership
>   system can also provide an automated password-reset system that takes
>   a user-supplied question and response.
>
> Exposing a unique identification for authenticated users that you can
>   use in your own applications and that also integrates with the ASP.NET
>   personalization and role-management (authorization) systems.
>
> Specifying a custom membership provider, which allows you to
>   substitute your own code to manage membership and maintain membership
>   data in a custom data store

Also, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996564/can-i-run-multiple-websites-under-a-single-membership-database) for some additional info.

Comment: But this is just for the web app's database access, not application user management. This is the user that connects to the sql database.

Comment: Not for connecting to the database, it is for users logging in to the site. And it's all SQL based, so there is nothing to stop you from calling the same stored procedures in a WinForms app.

Comment: Or did you mean that *your* question is how to maintain users and their connections to the database? If so, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep the user name and password in the registry.
- Build the connection string on the fly using a class
- All web sites and Apps should have the same class

By the way, the registry is more secure than the web config.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, as long as I can encrypt the password. But then I'd also need a tool to change the username and password.

Comment: What about using Windows Authentication for database access? Can't I setup web.config and app.config to use the authenticated user, and then password management is based on the user that has access to the machine?

Comment: That way, I won't have to encrypt anything. Does it sound plausible?

Comment: Windows Authentication is even easier. You include the authentication method in the web config and you don't include the user name or password in the connection string.

Comment: There are many encrypt/decrypt programs in .net. Most of them are free. You need to include the decrypt class in every site.